# R merge row which have a value lower than a threshold and close of minimum value

Tags: r, merge

I have a dataframe where each rows have an ID, and values activity. Below an example dataframe :

```
test=data.frame(
start=c(1,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,100,150,200),
end=c(50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,150,200,250),
sub_id=c("subid_1_1","subid_1_2","subid_1_3","subid_1_4","subid_1_5","subid_1_6","subid_1_7","subid_1_8","subid_1_9","subid_1_10","subid_1_11","subid_2_1","subid_2_2","subid_2_3"),
id=c(rep("id_1",11),rep("id_2",3)),
activity=c(-0.2,-0.6,-1,-1.2,-1.6,-1.6,-0.5,0.2,-1.2,-0.8,0.1,0.1,1.2,0.5))
```

For each rows which have the same ID :

I want to merge all the rows not separated by a value > -1 that are close to the min activity value. And keep the first value of start and last value of end for the merged rows and mean computed on the selected rows.

Expected output should be :

```
start    end    id    activity
100      300    id_1   -1.2
```

First I remove the line which have a greater value than -1

```
test=test[test$activity<=-1,]
```

I tried to merge rows using setDT

```
library("data.table")
final_test=setDF(setDT(test)[, .(start = min(start), end = max(end),activity=mean(activity)),by=id])
```

So it keeps the first and last element by id and compute mean of activity but it's not exactly what I want.

And this don't work

```
final_test=setDF(setDT(test)[, .(start = min(start), end = max(end),activity=mean(activity)),by=id[test$activity<=-1]])
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Min and Max are based on the condition that rows next to min(activity) have activity lower than -1. The start and end are directly next to the min(activity). Start/end have to be continous. I edit my question. I first remove the value greater than -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can create a `grp` column which will sequentially number the groups as 1, 2, etc - generated by an increment every time you see a value > -1.

```
library(dplyr)

threshold <- -1

test.group <- test %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(activity > threshold)) 

print(test.group, row.names = F)
```

Output:

```
 start end     sub_id   id activity grp
     1  50  subid_1_1 id_1     -0.2   1
    50 100  subid_1_2 id_1     -0.6   2
   100 150  subid_1_3 id_1     -1.0   2
   150 200  subid_1_4 id_1     -1.2   2
   200 250  subid_1_5 id_1     -1.6   2
   250 300  subid_1_6 id_1     -1.0   2
   300 350  subid_1_7 id_1     -0.5   3
   350 400  subid_1_8 id_1      0.2   4
   400 450  subid_1_9 id_1     -1.2   4
   450 500 subid_1_10 id_1     -0.8   5
   500 550 subid_1_11 id_1      0.1   6
   100 150  subid_2_1 id_2      0.1   7
   150 200  subid_2_2 id_2      1.2   8
   200 250  subid_2_3 id_2      0.5   9
```

Then you can remove values above -1 and group by the variable `grp`, then easily summarise to do what you want. You can make adjustments to the code to fine tune it if necessary.

```
test.result <- 
  test.group %>%
  subset(activity <= threshold) %>%
  group_by(id, grp) %>%
  summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end), activity = mean(activity)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(start, end, id, activity)

print(test.result, row.names = F)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  start   end id    activity
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
1   100   300 id_1      -1.2
2   400   450 id_1      -1.2
```

If you also want to bring details of the activity with shortest duration within the group, you can proceed as follows:

```
test.result <- 
  test.group %>%
  subset(activity <= -1) %>%
  group_by(id, grp) %>%
  arrange(activity) %>%
  summarise(
    start.min = first(start),
    end.min = first(end),
    sub_id.min = first(sub_id),
    activity.min = first(activity),
    start = min(start), 
    end = max(end), 
    activity = mean(activity)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(start, end, id, activity, start.min, end.min, sub_id.min, activity.min)
```

Output

```
  start   end id    activity start.min end.min sub_id.min activity.min
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>             <dbl>
1   100   300 id_1      -1.2       200     250 subid_1_5          -1.6
2   400   450 id_1      -1.2       400     450 subid_1_9          -1.2
```

Comment: Exactly what I expected. Thank you dear

Comment: Do you think that it's possible to add some column in order to have by row the subregion with minimal value.
For example row 1 : add 200 250  subid_1_5 id_1     -1.6   2

Comment: Yes it is possible. I'll do that improvement for you.

Comment: Thanks I tried to add to summarise : 
start_edge=start[min(activity)],end_edge=end[min(activity)],activity_edge=min(subregion_activity). But it's not working I got Erreur : Column `start_edge` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2. But it work for edge activity I got the right results. But I cannot got the start and end of the minimal activity
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What I did was to sort each group by activity so the smallest value comes first and then I can use the aggregate function first(). That was a little trick. You should always think of using aggregate functions within summarise.

Comment: Really perfect ! Thank you so much

Comment: I just think about the fact to have columns with minimal value. It works but I got always the first value. I edited my example. Let's imagine that the 2 or 3 first row have the same minimal value. How can I have the min(start_min) and the max (end_min) ?
For example now I expect start_min 200 end_min 300. So I think to drop the subid
I tried by my self but I'm stuck...
Thanks !